# FIFO one clock Head and Tail error - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fifo

After some advice on this site I've decided to use one clock FIFO. I've simulated it without errors before synthesizing it, after synthesize I've simulated code and I get this error:

> ## ** Warning:  Read and Write to same address at same time.  RD is unpredictable, driving RD to X
>
> ## Time: 200877700 ps  Iteration: 1  Instance: /testbench/FIFO/memory_tile_I_1

But simulations works like expected. After compiling I simulated again the code and I didn't get this error and simulation worked like expected.

My code is:

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity FIFO is
    Generic (
        constant DATA_WIDTH  : positive := 8;
        constant FIFO_DEPTH : positive := 500
    );
    Port ( 
        Clock       : in  STD_LOGIC;
        WriteEn : in  STD_LOGIC;
        DataIn  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        ReadEn  : in  STD_LOGIC;
        DataOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        Empty   : out STD_LOGIC;
        Full    : out STD_LOGIC;
        ModuleRESET : in STD_LOGIC
    );
end FIFO;

architecture FIFO_archi of FIFO is
    type FIFO_Memory is array (0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal Memory : FIFO_Memory;
    signal Head : natural range 0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1;
    signal Tail : natural range 0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1;


    begin
         -- Memory Pointer Process
        process (Clock, ModuleRESET)
            variable Looped : boolean;
        begin
            if ModuleRESET = '0' then
                Head <= 0;
                Tail <= 0;
                Looped := false;
                Full  <= '0';
                Empty <= '1';
                DataOut <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge(Clock) then  
                if ReadEn = '1' then             
                    if ((Looped = true) or (Head /= Tail)) then
                        -- Update data output
                        DataOut <= Memory(Tail);
                        -- Update Tail pointer as needed
                        if (Tail = FIFO_DEPTH - 1) then
                            Tail <= 0;
                            Looped := false;
                            else
                                Tail <= Tail + 1;
                            end if;
                     end if;
                elsif WriteEn = '1' then
                        if ((Looped = false) or (Head /= Tail)) then
                            -- Write Data to Memory
                            Memory(Head) <= DataIn;
                            -- Increment Head pointer as needed
                            if (Head = FIFO_DEPTH - 1) then
                                Head <= 0;
                                Looped := true;
                            else
                                Head <= Head + 1;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                end if;
                -- Update Empty and Full flags
                if (Head = Tail) then
                    if Looped then
                        Full <= '1';
                    else
                        Empty <= '1';
                    end if;
                else
                    Empty   <= '0';
                    Full    <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

end FIFO_archi;
```

I get this error every time I write the first data in simulation after synthesize(with synplify pro):

- When I initialize the code and write first data
- Every time I empty FIFO buffer and write first data

Of course I have Tail and Head at position 0 when my buffer is empty, but since I have two flags with an if-elseif istance, how it's possible I get an error on Read and Write same address?

Comment: You could try asking the guy you got this code from [here](http://www.deathbylogic.com/2013/07/vhdl-standard-fifo/)

Comment: You should absolutely not have an elsif for your write enable.  Reads and Writes are allowed to happen on the same clock cycle for a FIFO and your model should be able to handle that.

Comment: I suggest looking at how `ReadEn` is synthesized. It seems like it isn't directly connected to the RAM block for your architecture and the simulation model is complaining when a write happens while the `Tail = Head` because the memory is always reading.

Comment: I forget to specify that I never write and read at the same time, so when WEnable is 1 REnable is 0 and when REnable is 0 WEnable is 1.

Comment: You can ignore this warning. It looks like the way it was synthesized, the actual memory block is read every cycle, but the value is only used when your `ReadEn` is `'1'`. When you first do your write, the read value *is* unpredictable (X), but you don't care because the value isn't propagated anyway.

Comment: In your code they are independent but that only controls the enable for the `DataOut` register which may or may not be integrated with the RAM module. The synthesizer may have configured the RAM module to be in a mode where reads are always active. You have to look at the synthesized netlist to be sure.